# How to make Python web application private?

Tags: python, web, ip, private, werkzeug

I am developing Python back-end web application. Work-time management is also included into the application. The question that I am asking for is:

Ex. we have 3 locations that will use this application (Canada, USA and Europe). I want to be able somehow pre-define IP addresses of these three locations so employees can not access this web application from home. I think there could be something like VPN network for this application but it could be better if I can define a list of IP addresses in the application so only those IP addresses can have access to the application.

Thank you

Comment: Your webserver(i.e. apache, nginx, etc) can probably filter by ip address otherwise you'll have to tell us which framework your web app is in(twisted, django,...). Also code please.

Comment: We use Werkzeug, SqlAlchemy and Jinja2 for development

Comment: IP Address spoofing with IPv4 is pretty trivial. If the web application really needs to be 'private', look into username/password/token/ 2 factor authentication methods.

Comment: Thank you. Can you send me a link for 2-token authentication hint how to implement

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Django, You can use geoip and get the IP address. After that you can apply the filter.

Comment: We use Werkzeug, SqlAlchemy and Jinja2 for development

Answer (score 0):

You most definetly want to install OpenVPN on the same server the application is running and only allow requests from the IP range OpenVPN's DHCP server is using.

VPNs will allow you to restrict access to any network service you're providing -- be it a webapp, a mail- or print-server.